# Display custom table rows based on wordpress user login

Tags: php, wordpress, html-table, rows

I've uploaded a custom table of race times for a local team.  Each row includes the worpdress user ID.  I'm able to show the table one people are logged in, but I want to only show the lines tagged with the user's ID.  That way, when they log in, they only see their times.

Here's what I have to display the full table:

---

```
<?php

if (is_user_logged_in()):

    global $wpdb;
    $TIMES = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM TIMES;");


    echo "<table>";
    foreach($TIMES as $TIMES){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$TIMES->EVENT."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$TIMES->Race."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$TIMES->Time."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$TIMES->Meet."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$TIMES->Swimmer."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$TIMES->users_login."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
else:
    echo "Sorry, only registered users can view this information";
endif;
?>
```

---

Is there an easy way to show lines based on the user login?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php

if (is_user_logged_in()):

    $userid = get_user_id();

    global $wpdb;
    $TIMES = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM TIMES WHERE userid = '$userid';");


    echo "<table>";
    foreach($TIMES as $TIMES){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$TIMES->EVENT."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$TIMES->Race."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$TIMES->Time."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$TIMES->Meet."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$TIMES->Swimmer."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$TIMES->users_login."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
else:
    echo "Sorry, only registered users can view this information";
endif;
?>
```

where

get_user_id() will return the current userid

for instance

```
function get_user_id(){
    return $_SESSION['userid'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Its still not working. I've also tried updating the where to: ("SELECT * FROM TIMES WHERE users_login = 'xxxx';");   If I manually type out the login, it will work.  Once I inject the get_user_ID, something breaks and the screen is empty, the table is not displayed.  I've tried exactly what you suggested. Then I kept my static option (xxxx).  Without the get_user_id, it works...but as soon as I put that in, it stops.  Should I be entering the function you list too?

Comment: In wordpress this function is called: get_current_user_id(); Could you try to use get_current_user_id() instead of my example function?

Comment: Thanks Bas, but its still not working. I've tried a ton of options. As soon as I enter $userid = get_user_id(); the table no longer shows - Even if I keep the users_login = '2'    If I use your suggested code as-is, no table appears. It seems the get_user_id() is not linking with the field in the table.

Comment: Could it be there is not data for that user in the table? Please check. Then you could compare the output of get_current_user_id(); to the value in your table. Try: echo get_current_user_id(); to see when the current WP id is. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Bas, yes I'm sure there is data.  I even put various parts of the user data in the table (ID, email, login).  I set up a few different options so if it worked, I would know what its connecting.  I'll try your suggestions and see what that tells me. thanks